# Does this Maven plugin really have an invalid descriptor?

Tags: java, maven-2

**COMMAND:**

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.0-alpha-4:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.beardedgeeks -DarchetypeArtifactId
=gae-eclipse-maven-archetype  -DarchetypeVersion=1.1.2 -DarchetypeRepository=http://beardedgeeks.googlecode.com/svn/repository/release
s
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager getting plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin': Plugin 'org.apache.maven
.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.0-alpha-4' has an invalid descriptor:
1) Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong group ID: net.kindleit
2) Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong artifact ID: maven-gae-plugin
3) Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong version: 0.5.9
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 09 20:48:35 CEST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a hard time believing this Maven plugin has an invalid descriptor since other people seem to be using it with no problem. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't reproduce your problem, the following command works fine for me (copied & pasted from [GAE + Eclipse + Maven Archetype](http://hamandeggs.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/how-to-gae-eclipse-maven/)):

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.0-alpha-4:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.beardedgeeks \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=gae-eclipse-maven-archetype \
  -DarchetypeVersion=1.1.2 \
  -DarchetypeRepository=http://beardedgeeks.googlecode.com/svn/repository/releases
```

Tested with Maven 2.2.1:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 21:16:01+0200)
Java version: 1.6.0_20
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.32-22-generic" arch: "i386" Family: "unix"
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try Linux next.

Answer (score 2):

I often experience problems with crappy metadata in my local repository. This kind of error usually vanishes after I do

```
rm -Rf my/home/dir/.m2/repository/net/kendleit/maven-gae-plugin
```

but actually the reason why it works with Pascal is that Pascal uses this url `http://beardedgeeks.googlecode.com/svn/repository/releases` whereas you use this url `http://beardedgeeks.googlecode.com/svn/repository/release` (an s is missing, hence there's a 404)

do the rm as mentioned above and then run again with the correct url

---

EDIT: sorry there is actually a trailing s I didn't see. I take everything back, but still: try to delete the metadata in your local repo

Comment: +1 Bad metadata are very likely the root cause (it's been a while since I faced bad metadata though).

Comment: then your nexus is probably better than the one I am forced to work with :-)

Answer (score 0):

Reason: 
the GAV (groupid, artifactid, version) in Nexus (consequently in local repository and in the pom.xml) is not the same as the one in the jar file in \META-INF\maven\plugin.xml

This usually happens when you upload manually the plugin artifact in your own Nexus (or any other maven enterprise repository)

Solution:

- download the jar, see what are the GAV values in plugin.xml
- upload the jar on Nexus, passing as GAV the information from the plugin.xml
- Update the pom.xml accordingly

Make sure to remove from Nexus the old inconsistent artifact.